# OCaml basic use of a function

Tags: ocaml

I'm currently learning OCaml and I don't get along with the syntax. I didn't find any fitting advice in the web.
I basically want to call a function and reuse the result from it in the same function.

`find_by_name` is a function which finds the food by its name

`ingredients` is part of the record and a list

`avg` is a function which calculates the average

My function currently looks like that: It's terribly wrong but I don't know what to change.

`let avg_veggie_kcal name fd = find_by_name name fd -> avg x.ingredients`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a local let binding `let ... = ... in ...` to name intermediary results of some computation:

```ml
let some_function input =
  let intermediary_result = first_computation_step input in
  second_computation_step intermediary_result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let avg_veggie_kcal name fd = 
  match find_by_name name fd with 
    x -> avg x.ingredients
```

...assuming `find_by_name` returns a record with an `ingredients` field, and the `ingredients` field is of the input type to `avg`.

Comment: The pattern-matching in this case achieves the same result as using a local let binding but is more verbose. Now, if `find_by_name name fd` was a result that we wanted to match multiple patterns on, this would make more sense.  Also, if this is returning a record type, the match or local let binding can be used to make accessing that field easier.  `match find_by_name name fd with { ingredients=i; _ } -> avg i`